# Подпись строки DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь сделать подпись строк DataGridView в Visual studio 2017
Делаю также, как находил в интернете, но не работает ничего.

Матрица подгружается из matrix и если пытаться менять подпись строки до присвоения источника у DataGridView, то прога считает, что строк еще нет и выдает ошибку с индексом, а если после, то просто ничего не меняет.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < rowsNum; i++)
        {
            matrix.Rows.Add();
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = matrix;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = i;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать вот так:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "header1";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "header2";
```

Если не поможет, то сначала подставьте в источник данных пустой объект (не null), установите заголовки, а потом по готовности поменяйте DataSource.